# How to compute $H^1(\mathcal{I}_p(-2))$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a point $p\in\mathbb{P}^1$ and the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_p$, then we have an exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow\mathcal{I}_p(-2)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(-2)\rightarrow k(p)\rightarrow0$$
then one has
$$0\rightarrow H^0(k(p))\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{I}_p(-2))\rightarrow H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}})\rightarrow0$$
where $H^0(k(p))\cong k$ and $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}})\cong k$. What is the space $H^1(\mathcal{I}_p(-2))$?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Sasha I might have ask a silly question. Do we have $H^1(\mathcal{I}_p(-2))\cong k\oplus k$ because $\text{Ext}^1(k,k)=0$?

Comment: In fact, $\mathcal{I}_p \cong \mathcal{O}(-1)$, so $\mathcal{I}_p(-2) \cong \mathcal{O}(-3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$H^1(\mathcal{I}(-2)) \cong \mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{I}(-2)) \cong \mathrm{Ext}^0(\mathcal{I}(-2), \omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}) ^*= \mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{I}(-2),\mathcal{O}(-2))^* = \mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{I},\mathcal{O})^*.$$
The first isomorphism is by the general fact that $\mathrm{Ext}^k(\mathcal{O},\mathcal{F})\cong H^k(X,\mathcal{F})$, for $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf. The second isomorphism is Serre Duality. The others follow from the fact that $\mathrm{Ext}^0=\mathrm{Hom}$ and $\omega_{\mathbb{P}^1} = \mathcal{O}(-2)$.

On $\mathbb{P}^1$, the ideal sheaf of a point is (isomorphic to) $\mathcal{O}(-1)$. So, the last space is $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{O}(-1),\mathcal{O})^* = H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(1))^*$. This is a vector space of dimension $2$.